# Float.parseFloat return value for big number

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point

I'm trying parse  string 10651565.29  to float using `Float.parseFloat("10651565.29")`.
But I get 1.0651565E7.

I tried to look for documentation for this but not luck.
I'm using Java 8, any one know where I can find documentation for `Float.parseFloat`

What is the largest number `Float.parseFloat` can parse as is? Is it about the number of digits?

```
 float f = Float.parseFloat("10651565.29");
 System.out.println(" 10651565.29 = " +  f);
```

Comment: "But I get 1.0651565E7" - there's nothing wrong with that. Note that a `float` is just a number, it does not know anything about how you want it to be formatted when you print it. So there's no reason why it should print exactly as `10651565.29`, as you seem to expect. Also, the precision of `float` is limited to approximately 6 or 7 decimal digits, and your input number has 10 digits, so it will be impossible to store this number with 10 digits of precision in a `float`.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` instead of `float` if you need to store decimal numbers with arbitrary precision.

Comment: What you are actually complaining of is that `1.0651565E7` is not precisely equal to `10651565.29`.  Welcome to the wold of computer floating point.  `float` and `long` have limited **precision**.

Comment: maybe try [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) -- or use the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, as already suggested

Comment: The number 10651565.29 does not exist in IEEE-754 single-precision floating point.  The closest you can get is 10651565.00.  (Single precision has 24 bits of precision, and for the number 10651565, you use up all 24 bits on the integer part, with no bits left over for the fraction.)